# filelist sort to alphabetical order python

Tags: python

Hello I have to make program that sorts words.txt file to a list sorted alphabetically.

Like,

Words in an alphabetical order:

amazon

bike

cat

dog

my code:

```
file=open("words.txt")
print("words in an alphabetical order:")
linelist = file.read().splitlines()
linelist.sort()
print(linelist)
```

Problem there is that does print out
words in an alphabetical order:
['amazon', 'bike', 'cat', 'dog'..]

how to solve this out?

Comment: isnt the output is what youve expected ??

Comment: Not sure what the for loop is doing here!

Comment: Tried to edit. Should print out list, prints ['amazon','bike','cat'] And yes kris, loop was mistake, fixed. Newbie here so i had to edit a lot to make my question readable.

Comment: But `['amazon','bike','cat']` *is* a list. Do you want each entry to be printed on a separate line?

Comment: I guess the expected o/p is a new-line seperated list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
file=open("words.txt")
print("words in an alphabetical order:")
linelist = file.read().splitlines()
linelist.sort()
print('\n'.join(linelist))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of un-wanted code in your attempt. You need to read a file, sort the lines and then print it. It can be done in python with this line of code,

```
print(*sorted(open("word.txt", "r").readlines()), sep="\n")
```

Well, this is the functional piece. You need to handle the possible errors and other stuff. I think you need to get a grip on the language, and its features in a better way. All the best!